# can we use wild spelling in the query of Tiwtter search api ?

Tags: url, twitter

This page describes how to construct the query for twitter search. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

But it does not mention how to deal with the wildcard.

For example, if I want to search all keywords like this: smok*

smok* can represent Smoke, smoke, SMOKING, smoking, smoker etc. .

could I just simply say: q=smok* ?

I tried this, but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [search API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), there is no wildcard search available. Sorry.